Law of total probability for conditional probability
The law of total probability says that $P(A) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} P(A|B_i)\cdot P(B_i)$, where $B_i$s are a partition of $\Omega$. In the simple case: $P(A) = P(A|B) \cdot P(B) + P(A|\overline B)\cdot P(\overline B)$. Let us focus on the simple case, but rather in the sense of conditioned probability.
I have $A,B,C$. I want to compute $P(A|B)$, yet it is hard for me. I would like to consider $C$ and $\overline C$ as a partition of $A|B$. That is, I'm considering $A^* = A|B$ as a new event, and I am looking at $P(A^*) = P(A^* | C) \cdot P(C) + P(A^* | \overline C) \cdot P(\overline C)$. But is there a meaning in even writing $P(A^* | C)$? After all, it is $P\left( \left( A|B\right) | C \right)$ - does such an expression even make sense?
Or, maybe I should consider $P(A|B\cap C)$, but then how will I compute $P(A|B)$? Stating $P(A|B\cap C) \cdot P(C) + P(A|B\cap \overline C ) \cdot P(\overline C) = P(A|B)$ does not seem to be correct, nor does $P(A\cap C | B ) \cdot P(C) + P(A\cap \overline C | B) \cdot P(\overline C)=P(A|B)$.

$A\mid B$ is not an event, and so th OP's definition of $A^*$ is not meaningful.  $C$ and $\bar{C}$ do indeed constitute a partition of the sample space, and so one can write via the law of total probability that
$$P(A) = P(A\mid C)P(C) + P(A\mid \bar{C})P(\bar{C})\tag{1}.$$
Now, conditional probabilities (conditioned on the same event) constitute a probability measure. The practical use of the pontification in the previous sentence is that any valid result or formula in probability theory remains valid if everything is conditioned on the occurrence of some event. This is what allows us to start from a result such as $P(\bar{C}) = 1-P(C)$ and deduce that it must be that $$P(\bar{C}\mid B) = 1 - P(C\mid B).\tag{2}$$ So, let's condition everything in $(1)$ on the occurrence of $B$ to deduce that
\begin{align}
P(A\mid B) &= P(A\mid (C\cap B))P(C \mid B) + P(A\mid (\bar{C} \cap B))P(\bar{C}\mid B)\\
&= P(A\mid (B\cap C))P(C \mid B) + P(A\mid (B \cap \bar{C}))P(\bar{C}\mid B)\\
&= P(A\mid (B\cap C))P(C \mid B) + P(A\mid (B \cap \bar{C}))[1-P(C\mid B)].\tag{3}
\end{align}
In a comment on another answer, the OP seems to imply that the OP knows the value of $P(A\mid (B\cap C))$; presumably the OP also knows the value of $P(A\mid (B \cap \bar{C}))$, If so, all that is unknown in $(3)$ is the value of $P(C\mid B)$ which I hope that the OP knows, or can use Bayes' formula to deduce from the value of $P(B \mid C)$.

Let's focus on the general case — it's seemingly not to bad to understand it after working it out.
The law of total probability using conditional probability states that if $\xi$ is a universal set / sample space partitioned into mutually exclusive sets/events $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_n$ such that the collective union of all the $B$ events represents the whole sample $\xi$, then the probability of an event $A$ occurring in $\xi$ is:
$$P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A\ |\ B_i)\cdot P(B_i)$$

To understand this, let's start with the $n = 1$ base case. Here's a Venn Diagram to help you out:
n = 1 Venn Diagram
It seems intuitive that $A\cap B$ is the region where $A$ happens given that $B$ occurs, but what is the relationship between $P(A), P(A\ |\ B), P(A\cap B), P(B)$? Expressing $P(A\ |\ B)$ is the same as commenting on the probability that an element from $B$ belongs to $A$, which is the number of elements in $A\cap B$ over the number of elements in $B$. This means that:
$$\begin{align}P(A\ |\ B) &= \dfrac{|A\cap B|}{|B|} \\ &= \dfrac{|A\cap B|}{|\xi|} ÷ \dfrac{|B|}{|\xi|} \\ &= \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\end{align}$$
$$\therefore P(A\cap B) = P(A\ |\ B)\cdot P(B)$$

Now, we shall progress the prevous idea for any arbitrary $n \in \mathbb N$. Arbitrary n Venn Diagram
I genuinely hope the diagram is satisfactory for demonstration purposes...
Since all the events' collective union is equivalent to the sample space $\xi$, all the elements in $A$ is the collective union of all $A\cap B_i$; all the elements in $A$ are situated in some $B_i$, so no element of $A \in (B_1\cup B_2\cup \dots\cup B_n)'$. This means that:
$$\boxed{\therefore P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A\cap B_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A\ |\ B_i)\cdot P(B_i)}$$
Note that we used the result from the $n = 1$ case.

Thank you very much for the detailed response! However, I did not have any problem with understanding the law of total probability for $B_1,...,B_n$. My issue was when I would like to compute $P(A|B)$, yet it is hard for me. I can't easily express the probability $A$ occurs given that $B$ occurs. However, I can easily express this probability when I know $C$ occurs. So it is as if I am talking about $\left(A|B\right)|C$, but I believe this notion is not well defined. My question was about how the law of total probability will look like for $A^* = A|B$.

@dan I did not quite get what you meant...
